# How can i switch from WIFI connection to another if INTERNET connection is missing?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, vnc

i am somehow new to Ubuntu and Linux.

I am making some experiments in my home (VNC and remote access) but my internet connection is fast but very unstable (my WIFI signal is OK, but the service sucks in my country) when i leave my house and try to connect from another computer, sometimes all fails because of this faulty internet access.

How can i automate switching from two WIFI connections when one lost the internet access? i want to switch from my WIFI DSL if it fails, to my cellphone WIFI to have a "fail safe" system.

Don't know if i can make a script (i know some basic stuff in Python) or  can configure the network configuration to do that in Ubuntu?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "How can i automate switching from two WIFI connections when one lost the internet access?" That should happen automatically for any known connections you have stored.

Comment: Yes, when the connection of the WIFI is lost, but in my case the signal of the WIFI is fine, the one that is lost is the INTERNET access due to problems in the service. I mean that is why i separate term INTERNET from the WIFI signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way for resolve your issue is creating a system policy (or script), whose will ping some server on INTERNET for example 8.8.8.8 (google DNS). And when for example 5 packet loss, then it change network/gateway. I do this on Juniper or Cisco routers (or switchs L3), so this must be to do on linux, You need some route tools.

For me better option is to create routing option on your main router (if exist of course). All new home routers have options like DualWAN. This looks like you plug in SIM card or pick some another network/port (like your phone), and router internally monitoring connection and switching when this is necessary.